# How do I add custom permissions from a local database to my spring security principal object?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am having trouble adding custom permissions from our local database to my Spring Security Principal object.

My goals for our security is to do the following:

1. Authenticate with OAuth2 from our company (done)
2. Query our local database and gather user permissions (the query is written)
3. Add this list of permissions to my principal object for use throughout the application

I would prefer if this is done right when the user logs in using the configure() method in Spring Security configuration.

In more simple terms, I want to say "Hey, now that the user is logged in, take that username and plug it into this query. Take the results of that query, and add them to my principal object so I can use it anywhere in the application"

Here is my very simple security configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

}
```

Here is an example from my rest controller of gathering user information from my principal object:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("user")
@Slf4j
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/authentication")
    public Authentication getAuth(Principal principal){
        OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) principal;
        Authentication authentication = oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication();
        Map<String, String> details = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        details = (Map<String, String>) authentication.getDetails();
        return authentication;
    }


}
```

This works great, so I have the users email address, first name, last name, etc... that my company provides from their OAuth2 token. I just need to modify this principal object to add permissions... right when the user logs in...

Expected results:

I should have an principal object that has all the user information like email, first name, last name that my company provides from OAuth. Also, the principal object should have a list of permissions that we gathered from a custom database query.

Comment: i guess your service fetches the user information from somewhere using the token? because this is a resource server right? The resource server can't mutate principals.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Yeah my company's oauth implementation provides me with some basic info like email, first name, last name, username. I would like to query our local database using the username upon login, add those permissions to my OAuth principal object for use throughout the application.

Comment: read what i just wrote above the principal is final as soon as it gets created so you can not mutat a current one. What you need is to implement a custom `UserDetailsService` and a custom `UserDetails` object. All this can be found in spring security documentation.

Comment: I recommend taking 30 minutes to read through https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#technical-overview so you get a basic understanding of the different parts of spring security, as principal, UserDetailsService, AuthenticationManager.